# Limitations on client-side 3rd party querying? (JavaScript/AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, url, browser

What are the limitations on having a client query 3rd party URLs (ones with different domains than my site)?

Would I be able to make their browser query another site "behind the scenes" and send the response to me?

Would I be able to make them store a cookie from that site?

The reason I want to do this all is because I want to basically use another site as an API, even though they haven't written one.  In case you're wondering I do have permission to fetch from this site.

The reason I wanted to do it client-side is for speed reasons.. If my server doesn't have to do all the queries then things will go faster for my users..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to make XHRs to other domains.

Two options:

- Use a script tag, or JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON (they must support it)
- Create a proxy to the other server through your own server.

Comment: Re: script tags/JSONP, what are the differences between a local AJAX  query and thoses.  Any particular obstacles or limitations?  Re: the proxy, would the 3rd party server see the request as coming from me or from the client IP?

Comment: You CANNOT make AJAX requests (XHR) to a different server. But you are allowed to request a script from another server. The third party server would see the request as having come from your server's IP

Comment: What if there's no script on the 3rd party; just HTML?

Comment: Then you must do it using your own server as a proxy!

Comment: Guess so.  Either that or require users to install an app.  Thanks